# Can't insert string to Delta Table using Update in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have encountered an issue were it will not allow me to insert a string using update and returns. I'm running 6.5 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11), but it is not working on 6.4 runtime as well.

I have a delta table with the following columns, partitioned by the created date

```
ID string
 , addressLineOne string
 , addressLineTwo string
 , addressLineThree string
 , addressLineFour string
 , matchName string
 , createdDate
```

And I'm running a process that hits an API and updates the matchName column.

Using Pyspark if it do this, just to test writing

```
 deltaTable.update(col("ID") == "ABC123", {"matchName ": "example text"})
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1285.update.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: 'example
```

If I try this, change the string to 123, it updates without an issue

```
deltaTable.update(col("ID") == "ABC123", {"matchName ": "123"})
```

Yet if I use sql and do

```
UPDATE myTable SET matchName = "Some text" WHERE ID = "ABC123"
```

It inserts fine. I've searched and can't see a similar issue, Any suggestions? Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra space after `matchName` in your python code